# How to know odoo menu parent id?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8

I'm trying to make a module named travel_leave which inherits the "Leave Managements" module.

To create a new menuitem called "Travel leave request". It supposed to inherit and appear right after the "Leave request" menuitem under "Leaves" menu.

So how can I do it?

Here's my code in travel_leave_view.xml

```
<menuitem name="Travel Request"
              id="hr_holidays.menu_travel_request"
              parent="hr_holidays.menu_open_ask_holidays"
              sequence="11"/>
```

By doing this it created a new menuitem under Leaves but yet it isn't listed among the other menuitems.
[image]
[image]

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must define action in your Menu item.

Example:

```
<menuitem name="Travel Request"
              id="hr_holidays.menu_travel_request"
              action="action_travel_request" 
              parent="hr_holidays.menu_open_ask_holidays"
              sequence="10"/>
```

Thanks